# NoClassDefFoundError when adding SocialAuth in Eclipse 

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, socialauth

I tried to add an external library to my Android project but with no luck. My application crashed with an Exception at runtime:

```
09-06 07:44:41.921: E/AndroidRuntime(601): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter
```

Found many different magic solutions, but nothing helped:

1. Created directory "libs" and added JARs there.
2. Also added JARs in "Project properties → Java build path → Libraries"
3. In "Project properties → Java build path → Order and Export" moved JARs to top and checked it
4. Tried to clean project and even create new project.
5. Installed latest version of Eclipse.

I see the size of APK is changed when I add the library.

Any ideas?

Software used:

- Eclipse: Version: Juno Release Build id: 20120614-1722
- ADT: 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and none of the existing answers here solved the problem.

Then I checked the SocialAuth examples (which worked), and noticed that the jar name was different to mine - **socialauth-android.jar** instead of **socialauth-android-1.0.jar**

I used the **socialauth-android.jar** jar and the runtime error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define a new activity in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Put the below code inside `<application> ----</application>` tag of your manifest file.

```
<uses-library android:name="org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste the jar file in the libs folder go to *-> properties-> java build path->libraries-> 
  press Add jars ->*select your application libs folder 
  And select the jar file and press ok and  clear your project.

Comment: I've already tried this, read parts [1,2,3,4] in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, error caused by updating ADT. Try put this inside your `<Application>` tags in `Manifiest.xml` file

```
<uses-library android:name="org.brickred.socialauth...(your lib name)" />
```

And see for more if Ref Lib is checked in your prj properties: [**`Manage project libs`**](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)

Comment: I tried it and got new error:

    `Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY`

In logcat:

    `09-07 09:02:28.558: E/PackageManager(369): Package my.test.application requires unavailable shared library org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter; failing!`

JARs are still in libs and imported in "Java build path".

Comment: I dont think your lib got the name: `org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter`, pls re-check. it may be: `org.brickred.socialauth` (not for sure)

Comment: I expanded socialauth-android-1.0.jar in Project explorer, right-clicked on the library name inside it and selected "Copy qualified name" in context menu. That is, there is no error, I pasted copied name into manifest file. Here is line: `<uses-library android:name="org.brickred.socialauth.android" android:required="true"/>`. But still no success.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is a runtime error. It means that it is **NOT** important where and how you place your jars in your project (missing jars here would result in compile time errors). What is important is to make sure that your required jars are included in the built resulting jar. Try to open your compiled/generated jar file and check if it contains the required jars and that they are in correct place.

Comment: I'm new to Android development and don't have any knowledge about internals of build process. As the build result I have *.APK file, which is zip archive in fact. Inside it there is only one interesting file: classes.dex. When I add an external library to my project, this file becomes 2 times bigger. So I think library is actually added to the installation package. How can I check it?

Comment: The generated jar file is just a compressed file with different extension. You can open it with zip or rar utility to view the internal structure.

Comment: It looks like something else:

`$ file ./classes.dex 
classes.dex: Dalvik dex file version 035`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add jars supplied in sdk in your build path. Have you tried other examples inside sdk. If you still face the issue, you can mail to support of socialauth android.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have socialauth-*.jar and socialauth-android.jar in your libs folder try to right click on it and choose Build Path > Add to Build Path. In my case, the problem is gone when I got "**Referenced Libraries**" in my project.